# PyCharm doesn't list python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, linux-mint

My PyCharm doesn't list the latest interpreter when choosing the location of the interpreter in the preferences.

version: PyCharm 2018.1

operating system: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

```
$ ls /usr/bin/python3*
/usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.5m  /usr/bin/python3.6-config  /usr/bin/python3.6-dbg-config  /usr/bin/python3.6dm-config  /usr/bin/python3.6m-config  /usr/bin/python3-dbg         /usr/bin/python3dm         /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python3.5  /usr/bin/python3.6   /usr/bin/python3.6-dbg     /usr/bin/python3.6dm           /usr/bin/python3.6m          /usr/bin/python3-config     /usr/bin/python3-dbg-config  /usr/bin/python3dm-config  /usr/bin/python3m-config
```

However, in the preferences of PyCharm, python3.6 is not selectable:
[image]

When I try to select python3 from the list it still uses python3.5 even though python3 is a symbolic link to python3.6:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3.6
```

In PyCharm, I still get:

```
>> import sys
>> print(sys.version)
3.5.2 (default, Jan 10 2018, 06:17:28)
```

I am configuring the [Default Settings...] and also the project settings under [Settings...]

Comment: Why not use a virtual environment? I ran into this problem multiple times. Using a virtualenv solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not appearing in pycharm then you can add the path. Go to Settings>Project interpreter>Virtualenv Environment>...>add. Then make sure you path to python 3.6. Also do the same thing for System interpreter. Hope that helps

Comment: When I add a New environment I get the error `Read-only file system: '/usr/bin/python3.6'`. When I try Existing environment I hit the same problem of not seeing and not being able to select python3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Updating PyCharm might do the trick.

The Software Manager of Linux Mint currently only offers PyCharm 2018.1, but you can get a newer version by following the [instruction from the official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/install-and-set-up-pycharm.html#linux).

Installing the latest version of PyCharm using snap might help.

```
$ sudo apt install snapd
$ sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with the *Community* version where I couldn't add virtual environments based on other versions of Python than 2, 3, and 3.8.

Upgrading to the *Professional* version magically solved the problem for me.